# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'app:main' when setting up the virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, pyramid, configparser

I was using pyramid framework and set up the scaffold using pcreate command. When I call ../pserve development.ini, I ran into a no sectionerror.

```
Victors-MacBook-Pro:firefly yuanshizhan$ ../pserve development.ini 
bugsnag.configuration.release_stage = development
** [Bugsnag] Notifying http://notify.bugsnag.com of exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../pserve", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 51, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 316, in run
    global_conf=vars)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 340, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/bin/firefly/earn/__init__.py", line 151, in main
    config.scan()
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 930, in scan
    ignore=ignore)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/lib/python2.7/site-packages/venusian-1.0-py2.7.egg/venusian/__init__.py", line 205, in scan
    __import__(modname)
  File "/Users/yuanshizhan/send_mail/bin/firefly/earn/depositgoal.py", line 41, in <module>
    DB_URL = PARSER.get("app:main", "sqlalchemy.url")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'app:main'
```

I am pretty sure 'app:main' is inside the development.ini. Is there anyway to resolve this? like directing the method into development.ini file?

Comment: Your `PARSER` is an instance of ConfigParser, you will have to tell it where to find the appropriate file to parse to get the sqlalchemy.url.